# Descendant of sibling jquery

Tags: jquery

I have recently switched from using XPath to using jQuery selectors. I am having trouble with a particular XPath selector I would use:

//h1[contains(.,'Some Title')]//following::a[1]

Basically I get the first link element from a descendant of a sibling.

From what I understand jQuery selects descendants as "ancestor descedant" and selects siblings as "sibling + sibling".

How do I combine these when I don't care/know what the sibling tag is? (In other words "h1 + ul a" works but I want to leave out the ul if possible"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only one sibling for your H1, you can use

```
$('h1').siblings().find('a')
```

If you want to use exactly the NEXT sibling, do

```
$('h1').next().find('a')
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like jQuery('ancestor descendant') ?

Check out http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/

For example:

```
$("h1 a")
```